# materialized view advantage to have underlying table with constraint index

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume I have a materialized view a such:

```
create materialized view my_mat_view as
select * 
from tb1
join tb2
on tb1.id = tb2.f_id and
tb1.col1 = tb2.col2
```

Now is there a difference in speed when making different queries from `my_mat_view` if `tb2` has or not a foreign key constraint to `tb1` ?
I believe a materialized view is not like a view and thus, it will only execute the underlying query construction when I refresh it, right ? But what about when I select from it ? I can also create an index for `my_mat_view` on the columns belonging to `tb2` which are supposed to be foreign keys , would that have the same effect ?

In summary, I would like to know if building a relationship between two tables that a mat view derives from can increase speed query times for that mat view ?

Answer (score 2):

A materialized view is essentially a table that can't be directly updated and has an associated query that is used to refresh its contents; therefore, selecting from a materialized view is unaffected by the presence of constraints or indexes on the tables from which it is built. Indexes can be created on materialized views to improve query performance.